# Android how send command

Tags: android

i want to send string  command in android like do in vb but i don't to know like translate

this is an example

char(&H1D) + "V" + char(20) + char(65)

how can translate in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ascii code. Char(20)=¶,char(65)=A
in Android, you can try:

```
String sMessage = "V" + (char)20 + (char)65;
```

Comment: H1B or H1D. &H1D = (char)29 = ↔